# Lenovo Y50 SSD upgrade - powering on issues

Tags: boot, ssd, upgrade, power, lenovo-laptop

I recently upgrade my laptop (Lenovo Y50) from a 1TB HDD to an equivalent 1TB SSD from Samsung. I used EaseUS ToDo copying tool. When the computer boots up, everything works BEAUTIFULLY! Better than I can imagine (first time upgrading to SSD). However, there is one small issue, rather extremely annoying; every now and then when I attempt to power on the computer, the laptop power button and keyboard backlight will turn on (screen will not), but after a few seconds, the laptop will turn off for a few more seconds and then loop through this process FOREVER. Sometimes holding down the power button throughout this loop will finally allow it to load, sometimes not. Sometimes it'll load by itself after a few loops, but most of the time not. I've tried various settings to prevent this from occurring such as plugging it into power, making sure it has a full charge, holding down power button for various amounts of time.

This usually occurs in the event that I turn off the computer (whether it is improperly shut down or properly), and then within the next 20-30 mins, attempt to boot the computer again. The only fix I've found is to just leave the computer alone for several hours, and most of the time it'll boot just fine. There were a few times though that it would go through the boot loop even though it had been off for well over 24 hrs, but not often.

This is not how I want my computer to work, nor should it behave this way. And I'm not too sure that it was because of the SSD upgrade because I upgraded my desktop PC (Dell XPS 27) and it's working just fine. However, I have no idea how to begin to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Did you reconnect all the power connectors correctly? Does the laptop do this behaviour while on battery or on normal power?

Comment: Yes everything is plugged in correctly. It was just a little 2.5" drive, and the power and data sata connectors are one solid connection piece. I haven't tried switching up the power mode, but I'll give it a try.